# Excel - check multiple true/false conditions

Tags: excel

I have three cells which can either contain `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Then in another cell use a formula to check that **only one** cell contains true. If multiple of these cells are true, than I want to display an error message.

F4,G4 and H4 is where the values are written:

```
F4: True or False
G4: True or False
H4: True or False
```

Then in D4 I need to make my check. At the moment I can only figure out how to check if one of two fields contains true/true:

```
=IF(AND(F4=TRUE;G4=TRUE);"Only one true value allowed!";"Success!")
```

Is it possible to extend above function to check whether all three cells contains **one** `TRUE` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use countif to check how many cells contain True, and use an if statement to return a message depending on that value.

In cell D4 use this formula:

`=IF(COUNTIF(F4:H4,"True")>1,"Only one true value allowed!","Success!")`

As mentioned in the comments the formula would not chek for all three acounts being false, here is an update to the formula to correct the issue:

`=IF(COUNTIF(F4:H4,"True")>1,"Only one true value allowed!",IF(COUNTIF(F4:H4,"True")<1,"Only one true value allowed!","Success!"))`

And to add to that we can add a countblank to make sure all cells contain some data:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F4:H4,"True")>1,"Only one true value allowed!",IF(COUNTIF(F4:H4,"True")<1,"Only one true value allowed!",IF(COUNTBLANK(F4:H4)>0,"Only one true value allowed!","Success!")))
```

further changes could be made to make sure only true or false are within each cell.

Comment: This formula will also evaluate to "Success!" when all three cells are false. @pnuts's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
=SIGN(F4)+SIGN(G4)+SIGN(H4)=1
```